# Arduino SPI GPS NanoHornet 1411 PM04

Tags: arduino, gps, arduino-uno, spi, arduino-ide

Good afternoon.

I am new to the SPI protocol and Arduino. Recently I came across a GPS sensor, this one: Nano Hornet 1411 PM04 (Datasheet: https://www.origingps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Nano-Hornet-ORG1411-Datasheet2.pdf).

I have read already many information a lot of about SPI (including some tutorials from Sparkfun for Arduino), but I still can't make this GPS work...

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand how to write code for Arduino Uno that can make this sensor run.

For further information:

- The pins of this sensor are displayed on page 21 of the link provided before for the datasheet (block 17: INTERFACE of the index).
- The electronics schematics I have implemented is the one from the lower picture on page 25 (block 18: TYPICAL APPLICATION CIRCUIT of the index, FIGURE 11 – REFERENCE SCHEMATIC DIAGRAM - PM04 ORDERING OPTION).
- Option chosen is SPI assembled (No R1, R2, R3, R4 placed).
- Vcc is the 3.3 V pin source from the Arduino Uno board.
- Clock, MISO, and MOSI pins are 13, 12 and 11 respectively on Arduino Uno
- Slave select would be at digital pin 10.
- ON_OFF signal is controlled by a transistor linked to digital pin 8, which allows the 3.3 V to make the pulse to start the device.

My bigger misunderstanding for this specific implementation is the fact that I don't know/understand how I can read from the GPS sensor or what I should send to the sensor to start transmitting the position. Besides that, I don't also understand how the data is output...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The Hornet uses the NMEA standard.  You should start by reading the information on this page, this should set you on the right path.

https://playground.arduino.cc/Tutorials/GPS

Comment: Thank you very much, I have already read it and I have things slightly clear about the output, the problem I am encountering now is that I still can't manage to make it work with the SPI configuration...